# Why can't this application be deactivated after screen is locked?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, battery-life, huawei

I recently installed WhatsApp. I thought it would be clever to deactivate it while my screen is locked to save battery: data can update when I have my screen active.

But it looks there is something special about this application that prevent it from being deactivated.

- I often get notifications involving WhatsApp in high consumption while my phone is locked
- there is a red message ***Can't refresh when closed*** on it's side when I go to "Battery > Close apps after screen lock" ... well, that's pretty much what I would like!

[image: WhatsApp cannot refresh when closed]

Anyone knows what I can do to avoid this? (*apart from uninstalling this tyrannic application*)? Is there a feature I'm missing and that I should change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WhatsApp employs a mechanism that ensures messages are always notified (as long as data connectivity is present) , which is well explained here [How is WhatsApp able to receive messages when not in use?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/43970/131553). That's the reason on your device, the red warning is displayed

You can instead *Greenify* WhatsApp . For details  see [greenify](/questions/tagged/greenify) questions like [How does hibernating an app work technically?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/63572/131553) and [XDA - Greenify](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2155737)

**Edit** *Protected apps* feature may be used. I am not sure if this feature exists in the emui version you have. [What is protected apps in Huawei phones?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/152649/131553)

Comment: Thanks, I can't see greenify wiki (it doesn't look like it exists).

Comment: Oops. My bad... That tag doesn't have a wiki but questions in it should help

Comment: Edited to add XDA link too

Comment: Added another possibility - see edit

Comment: I was able to install *greenify*. However, its not simple to configure, and it appears it caused connection losses to my other applications when network was bad. I finally uninstalled it.

Comment: I am surprised to hear that, but yes, it's a powerful app and needs to be understood to prevent such instances

Answer (score 1):

My solution was to deactivate unwanted "battery usage notifications" for Whatsapp: it doesn't consume that much after all, compared to other applications.