# Is there a method to freeze and thaw an application vs uninstall/reinstall?

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, disable-app

On a non-rooted Android 5.1 phone, is there a way to "freeze" an applications, settings, and data?

I don't want to uninstall or need to consistently kill a process. I would like to archive an application, and when I need it, take a brief moment to "thaw" it, use it, and freeze again when done.

Comment: Is your device rooted?

Comment: No. I'd prefer not to root it. This is my main phone and my primary 2FA device.

Comment: And the apps you want to "freeze" are pre-installed ones, or user-installed? In the latter case, "hibernating" them would be sufficient?

Comment: You could use the command-line solution. `adb shell pm hide package` will do, where `package` is package name of the app.

Comment: If the app can be backuped you can create a backup of the apk+data via adb: `adb backup -f mybackup.ab -apk <packagename of app>`. When you need the app again you can restore the mybackup.ab file. This works on non-rooted phones.

Comment: @Izzy These would be downloaded apps! (upvote)

Comment: @Robert Please list that as an answer. While I hope to do this from my device, I'm certainly happy to have a CLI option! (upvote)

Answer (score 2):

You shoud try a software developped by [gatesjunior](https://forum.xda-developers.com/member.php?u=3178012), a Recognized Developer at XDA-Developers. I doesn't require root for hiding/blocking apps.

- Download debloater.exe [here](http://rootjunkysdl.com/files/?dir=Gates/DeBloater) ([mirror](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=8576a478a6dbc737!1203&authkey=!ADxKbf8WcIv3t5Q&ithint=file%2Cexe)) for Windows (May require .Net Framework 3.5 or higher). Download dmg file for OSX [here](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=8576a478a6dbc737%21831)
- Enable USB debugging on the phone
- Connect the phone to the computer (Should install drivers to get the phone detected)
- Run debloater, clikc on "Click here togin"- should list all installed apps. Just check the check-mark related to the apps you want to hide/disable then click the first icon in the top left.

[image]

I found the complete link on how to use the software, check it out [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/software/debloater-remove-carrier-bloat-t2998294)

Comment: Another great suggestion. Upvote. For my situation though, I run linux everywhere, and haven't had great experiences with Android tools over Wine. Still holding old for the unicorn of non-rooted and on the phone. But again, many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you have ADB enabled on your device and the app allows to backup it's data you can use the connected PC to backup the app data and the app APK file using the adb backup command:

```
adb backup -f mybackup.ab -apk <packagename of app>
```

When you need the app again you can restore the mybackup.ab file. This works on non-rooted phones.

Note: If the app denies backup the backup will not fail, the data wil be just empty. Therefore It may be wise to execute the adb backup command first without the `apk` option. If the created backup file has a size of more than a few bytes most likely the app allows data backup.

Comment: Still hoping for an on-the-device answer, but this is definitively a runner-up. Thanks. Up vote.

Comment: Important note: This doesn't work for all apps. If you end up with a 0 or 41 byte file, the app in question has blocked itself from being backed up (`ALLOW_BACKUP=FALSE`). // And btw: the on-device-variant of Robert's advice is [Helium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.backup) :)

Comment: @Izzy - That might be the correct answer. Would you mind creating an entry for it. Testing this soon.

Comment: @Richard [done](/a/171496/16575), with additional instructions. Enjoy!

Answer (score 1):

As your targets are "downloaded apps" you've installed yourself, I'd suggest you take a look at **[Greenify](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oasisfeng.greenify):**

[image: Greenify] [image: Greenify]
<sup>*Greenify* (source: [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oasisfeng.greenify); click images for larger variants)</sup>

> Greenify help you identify and put the misbehaving apps into hibernation when you are not using them, to stop them from lagging your device and leeching the battery, in a unique way! They can do nothing without explicit launch by you or other apps, while still preserving full functionality when running in foreground, similar to iOS apps!

Once you've defined the apps to deal with, you're done: use them as you always do, no manually handling required. *Greenify* takes care that those apps are not running when you're not using them.

*Greenify* works even without root, though not all of its features will be available then. It unleashes its full power, though, only on rooted devices having the *XPosed* framework installed: Then you can also deal with system apps.

For further details, also see:

- [How does hibernating an app work technically?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/63572/16575)
- [Android's native process management vs. Greenify](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/140427/16575)
- [How to Optimize Your Android Phone's Battery Life with Greenify](https://www.howtogeek.com/198135/how-to-optimize-your-android-phones-battery-life-using-greenify/) (HowToGeek)
- [How to Use Greenify App](https://www.orduh.com/use-greenify-app-extend-android-battery-life/) (Orduh)

Answer (score 0):

As a variant to [Robert's answer](/a/170798/16575), but working on-device: **[Helium Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.backup)** does ADB backups directly there. If your device is not rooted, it will however need to be initialized via its desktop component after each boot.

[image: Helium] [image: Helium] [image: Helium]
<sup>*Helium* (source: [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.backup); click images for larger variants)</sup>

Other than with [my other approach](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/170799/16575), you'd need multiple steps here to "freeze" it:

1. backup the app using *Helium*
2. uninstall the app (e.g. via *Settings › Apps)

However, "unfreezing" would just mean to restore it.

As I commented on Robert's answer: before deleting the app, make sure a proper backup was achieved. Developers can chose to have their apps opt-out of this, setting `ALLOW_BACKUP=FALSE`. In this case, one usually ends up with a 41 byte file (just containing the "backup header", but neither app nor data). Also make sure to tick the box for inclusion of the `.apk` file (see second screenshot), or you might have another surprise :)

Side-effect: As the 3rd screenshot shows, you can use *Helium* also to create regular backups on a schedule. Can't hurt :)

---

<sup>In case you wonder about the app being named "Carbon" in the screenshot: that was its former name, Koush obviously didn't remove it there.</sup>